# Inconsistent artifacts when rendering textures in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm just trying to render some simple particles in OpenGLES 2.0 in the iPhone Simulator, and sometimes there are artifacts, and sometimes there aren't, it's almost like it's a coin flip when I try to run my code. The first image is what it should look like, the second image are the artifacts, notice the lines/banding at the bottom. Same image, same code, different results, it has me stumped:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF2qS.png <-no artifacts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9dCc.png <-artifacts

Like I said, I have no idea where to begin, it's just a basic two triangle sprite with texture coordinates of (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1). If you have any suggestions of what code I should post, I would appreciate it

Edit:

Here's my texture loading code.

```
CGImageRef image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename].CGImage;
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
NSUInteger length = width*height*4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(length*sizeof(GLubyte));
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, width*4, CGImageGetColorSpace(image), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
CGContextRelease(context);

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

I switched the malloc call to calloc based on the suggestion to zero out the memory first, and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer since I don't know the exact solution, but I think I can hint at the problem.  It looks like you have a race condition where you are using a texture possibly before it is finished copying into memory.  Try to make use of the GL wait and sync operations if possible.

Comment: How are you loading the sprite images?  Are you using CoreGraphics?  Is the memory zeroed before you load into it?

Comment: Here's my texture loading code:

Comment: As @Frogblast noted, the memory should be set to zero before you use it, or garbage might come out as it does in your case.  Instead of `malloc` you should be using `calloc` (which zeros the memory) or `bzero`